# What is the simplest way to compose a bitmap image in a Windows Store App

Tags: c#, c++, bitmap, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am trying to develop a Windows Store App that generates and saves bitmap images which are composed of various images, primitive shapes and text. I don't necessarily want all the images to be on screen as there might be a lot of them which I need to generate. My app is written in C#. I see that Microsoft introduced a new RenderTargetBitmap class in Windows 8.1--which I am planning to target--but it only saves XAML trees that are on screen. Is my only choice to go with C++? If so what C++ library is free, compatible with WinRT and has a simple API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap). It allows you to draw pixels manually in an image, by first writing them out to a byte array.

If you need additional tools for rendering shapes and the like, [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) can be a good option. To quote from the link:

> The WriteableBitmap API is very minimalistic and there's only the raw
>   Pixels array for such operations. The WriteableBitmapEx library tries
>   to compensate that with extensions methods that are easy to use like
>   built in methods and offer GDI+ like functionality. The library
>   extends the WriteableBitmap class with elementary and fast (2D
>   drawing) functionality, conversion methods and functions to combine
>   (blit) WriteableBitmaps.

Comment: This looks very promising, I will give this a try.